# Why is low temperature required for optical lattice systems to enter magnetic regime?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-optics, cold-atoms

> "Optical lattice requires a very low temperature scale to enter magnetism regime."

*Why is that?*

What I know:

1. optical lattice systems suppress kinetic energy (hopping parameter: $t$ small);
2. superexchange is a second order process;
3. Therefore, the energy gap due to exchange will be small ($\Delta E\propto t^2$)

*Is that the reason?*

Comment: Please provide a reference for the quote you give. It will make answering your question much easier.

Comment: e.g. in the abstract of arXiv:1212.2634